UML: Ownership of Stereotypes
According to the UML 2.5.1 specification, a Stereotype must be owned (directly or indirectly) by a Profile, or by a Package which is contained in the Profile (diagram from p. 295):

However, on page 301-302 under section 12.3.3.4 Stereotypes, there is this sentence on p. 302:
"The type of a composite aggregation Stereotype Property cannot be a Stereotype (since Stereotypes are owned by their Extensions) or a metaclass (since instances of metaclasses are owned by other instances of metaclasses)..."
I do not understand how a Stereotype can be owned by an Extension. Is this a mistake? Probably "Profiles" should be substituted for "Extensions" here?

Read about dot notation on p. 18

@qwerty_so : Thank you! This helps, but now I think there is still a defect. Here is a quote from the page you suggested I read (under 6.4.2 Diagram Format): "Dot notation is used to denote association end ownership, where the dot shows that the Class at the other end of the line owns the Property whose type is the Class touched by the dot." The wording of p. 302 should then be: "The type of a composite aggregation Stereotype Property cannot be a Stereotype (since Stereotypes' Properties are owned by their Extensions)..." Then this item would make perfect sense!

The last bullet under section 12.3.3.1.3 "MOF-Equivalent Semantics" on p. 297-298 says: "An instance of a Stereotype (...) maps to an instance of the CMOF class representing the Stereotype. This stereotype instance is compositionally associated with the Element to which it applies using a Link that is an instance of the composite Association to which the Extension is mapped." (continued in next comment...)

(continued from the above comment...) That might have been the original intent of the spec. authors. In that case, the quote should be re-worded as follows: "The type of a composite aggregation Stereotype Property cannot be a Stereotype (since Stereotype instances are owned by their Extensions)..."

Maybe you are right. But filing a bug at OMG is futile (as for my experience). Maybe Axel will chip in since he is one of the reviewers. You might as well giving the bug report a try.

@qwerty_so I have created a new issue about this here: https://issues.omg.org/issues/spec/UML/2.5#issue-54691

Let's see what happens!

Just scroll up from your issue and (don') try to count them. My first one reported was this: https://issues.omg.org/issues/spec/UML/2.5#issue-26317
